# How to use hibernate appender instead of JDBCAppender for logging to database

Tags: hibernate, logging, jdbc, log4j

Currently we are using the Apache log4j Java-based logging utility. I want to log user activities to database tables, instead of writing old jdbc SQL queries.

Is there any Hibernate Appender already written like JDBCAppender for log4j?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly your requirement.

Googled for 'Hibernate Appender' and the first result returned was Hibernate Log4J Appender.

See [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernatelog4ja/) link.

Comment: yes ,but this seems in beta version,please suggest something prevail as established